# Reading an xml data using phpQuery

Tags: php, phpquery

I want to read the nodes from an xml file using phpQuery..I have tried the below code but its not working ..Can anyone plz help me with the syntax of parsing xml using phpQuery....

```
$file = 'demo.xml'
phpQuery::newDocumentFileXML($file, $charset = 'utf-8');

$nodeElement = pq('nodes'); 

    $node = $nodeElement->xml();
echo '<h2>Nodes:</h2>';
echo '<p>' . htmlentities( $title) . '</p>';
```

The above code is not working .....My syntax seems to be wrong...

Comment: Clarify 'its not working'.

Comment: I meant.. 'it's not working' is not really enough information.

Comment: Dude i mentioned that the syntax may be wrong and asked for proper syntax

Comment: So what are the symptoms of your problem.. try to explain what's happening. Are you getting an error? Nothing at all?

Comment: the page is just going on loading

Comment: That doesn't make a lot of sense tbh.. Can you be more specific.. Did you mean that the page never stops loading?

Comment: @Evert I am asking whether the syntax is proper or not ???.Yes the page never stops loading

Comment: For someone who has an issue, and asking others to help him solve it.. you are not particularly friendly. So I wish you good luck solving this.

Comment: You may think the questions are silly, but they are important to help debug. For example: the fact that the browser never stops reloading is pretty critical information, as it implies there's nothing wrong with the syntax of your PHP script; but there's something different going on under the hood. I practically had to drag that out of you.

Answer (score 0):

I use simplexml_load_file for most things why not use that? Where's an example using google maps api for pulling distance between 2 locations and storing the returned "text" value from the resultant xml into the $distance variable.  You can find examples of the xml as returned from google on their website.  The same can be used for your code instead of requesting a url though load a local xml file.

```
//create request url
                    $request_url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=".$tslocation->TransLat.",".$tslocation->TransLong."&destinations=".$sitelocation->SiteLat.",".$sitelocation->SiteLong."&sensor=false&units=metric";
                    //perform query
                    $xml = simplexml_load_file($request_url) or die("url not loading");
                    //get distance text
                    $distance = $xml->row->element->distance->text;
```

Comment: do you have a reason for it having to be in phpquery? do you have any errors in your apache error.log file for why what you currently have isn't working?

Comment: phpQuery because it supports the DOM model....If i want to retrieve a particular data from a specified class in an xml , phpQuery can do it

Comment: simple xml supports the xml dom just fine. phpquery from what I understand is just a php implementation of jquery for accessing the web client side dom.  nothing that cannot be achieved with normal jquery + simple xml in alot less code and with alot less issue.